# Is it possible to use an aspect oriented approach to logging in an Azure function with Autofac and DynamicProxy

Tags: c#, azure, dependency-injection, autofac, azure-functions

Is it possible to use an aspect oriented approach to logging in an Azure function with Autofac and DynamicProxy along the lines of:

https://nearsoft.com/blog/aspect-oriented-programming-aop-in-net-core-and-c-using-autofac-and-dynamicproxy/

I researched the following links

1. http://codingsoul.de/2018/01/19/azure-function-dependency-injection-with-autofac/
2. https://blog.wille-zone.de/post/azure-functions-proper-dependency-injection/
3. http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/interceptors.html

and then tried extending Holger Leichsenring's post (#1) with the code below.  However, the Intercept() function never was fired.   Any ideas?

## Additional Nuget References (you also need to downgrade Autofac to 4.0.1)

```
using Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy;
using Castle.DynamicProxy;
```

## TestIt

Add Interceptor and a function with a parameter...

```
[Intercept(typeof(ICallLogger))]
public class TestIt : ITestIt
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string CallMe()
    {
        return "Dependency Injection Test method had been called...";
    }

    public string CallMeWithParameter(string parameter)
    {
        return "Dependency Injection Test method had been called with [" + parameter + "]";
    }
}
```

## ServicesModule

```
public class ServicesModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<CallLogger>().As<ICallLogger>();
        builder.RegisterType<TestIt>().As<ITestIt>().EnableClassInterceptors();

        // How can you pass context to the AutoFac.ServicesModule()? Commenting out for now and using parameterless constructor instead.
        // builder.Register(c => new CallLogger(context.Trace)).Named<IInterceptor>("log-calls");

        // Switch to use Type based interceptor attribute instead of Name based interceptor attribute
        // builder.Register(c => new CallLogger()).Named<IInterceptor>("log-calls");

    }
}
```

## CallLogger

```
public interface ICallLogger
{
    void Intercept(IInvocation invocation);
}

/// <summary>
/// Logging class that would hopefully wrap TraceWriter - trying the Debug Output Window for now...
/// </summary>
public class CallLogger : IInterceptor, ICallLogger
{
    TraceWriter _log;

    public CallLogger(TraceWriter log)
    {
        _log = log;
    }

    public CallLogger()
    {
        _log = null;
    }

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        string message = string.Empty;

        message = "Calling method {0} with parameters {1}... " +
                  invocation.Method.Name +
                  string.Join(", ", invocation.Arguments.Select(a => (a ?? "").ToString()).ToArray());

        if (_log != null)
        {
            _log.Info(message);
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(message);

        invocation.Proceed();

        message = "Done: result was {0}." + invocation.ReturnValue;
        Debug.WriteLine(message);

        if (_log != null)
        {
            _log.Info(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you solved the issue (faced with similar)?

Comment: Indeed, any progress?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using [Autofac Type Interceptors](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/interceptors.html), but as you've discovered configuring the interceptors can be tricky. The easiest method I know of to achieve this is using [Functionless](https://github.com/LeastOne/Functionless). Full disclosure, its an open source project I authored. I'm not interested in self-promotion, just trying to help others. I only mention it here because so far as I know its the easiest way to achieve your objective, I'll gladly yield to other better solutions if posted.

Here's a complete gist, [FunctionAppLogingInterception](https://gist.github.com/LeastOne/700f550869a26c139a2d2cedc1792416), which you should be able to download, build and run, which demonstrates a simple logging interceptor. Here's a brief explanation ...

1. Configure an appropriate log-level in `host.json` (see [host.json reference for Azure Functions 2.x and later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#logging))

```
    "logLevel": {
      "FunctionAppLogingInterception": "Debug"
    }
```

2. Add your logger `IInterceptor` implementation which will be automatically picked up and registered by [Functionless](https://github.com/LeastOne/Functionless).

```
    public class LoggingInterceptor : IInterceptor
    {
        public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

3. Add a class with one or more `public` overrideable (i.e. marked `virtual` or `override`) methods you'd like intercepted as explained by [Autofac | Type Interceptors: Tips](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/interceptors.html#tips).

```
    public class ReportJob
    {
        [NewOrchestration]
        public virtual async Task ExecuteAsync()
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

4. Invoke your class using Functionless's built in orchestrator or add your own function trigger to invoke your class and the interceptor.

```
POST /api/orchestrator?$method=ReportJob.<ExecuteAsync>()
```

Or ...

```
[FunctionName("reportjob-execute")]
public async Task Execute(
    [HttpTrigger] HttpRequest request,
    [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient client)
{
    await client.DurablyInvokeAsync(
        async () => await this.reportJob.ExecuteAsync()
    );
}
```

```
POST /api/reportjob-execute
```

5. Observe the intercepted log output. If using the aforementioned gist ([FunctionAppLogingInterception](https://gist.github.com/LeastOne/700f550869a26c139a2d2cedc1792416)) it should produce output similar to the following (note the lines that end with "invoked") ...

```
[2020-12-22T18:20:10.816Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000D771FED2'.
[2020-12-22T18:20:16.207Z] Executing 'orchestrator' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=bdc7d19e-1250-4692-bde2-98cf663cacb8)
[2020-12-22T18:20:16.403Z] Executed 'orchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=bdc7d19e-1250-4692-bde2-98cf663cacb8, Duration=243ms)
[2020-12-22T18:20:16.481Z] Executing 'orchestration' (Reason='(null)', Id=2d17ea99-959c-43ef-b7ba-ed194de38165)
[2020-12-22T18:20:17.133Z] System.Threading.Tasks.Task ExecuteAsync() invoked
[2020-12-22T18:20:17.272Z] Executed 'orchestration' (Succeeded, Id=2d17ea99-959c-43ef-b7ba-ed194de38165, Duration=793ms)
[2020-12-22T18:20:17.339Z] Executing 'orchestration' (Reason='(null)', Id=ff5c08e7-f678-48a3-9a82-bc2e231195e3)
[2020-12-22T18:20:17.582Z] System.Threading.Tasks.Task GenerateReportsAsync() invoked
[2020-12-22T18:20:17.597Z] Executed 'orchestration' (Succeeded, Id=ff5c08e7-f678-48a3-9a82-bc2e231195e3, Duration=258ms)
[2020-12-22T18:20:17.642Z] Executing 'activity' (Reason='(null)', Id=cc4f89ef-f64c-4851-8e7c-3b7acbfcc915)
[2020-12-22T18:20:17.646Z] Executing 'activity' (Reason='(null)', Id=3a7747a6-5568-4561-a028-9c319263ccf7)
[2020-12-22T18:20:17.659Z] Executing 'activity' (Reason='(null)', Id=caea5602-9c0b-463a-b0b0-112e512eaf25)
[2020-12-22T18:20:17.808Z] System.Threading.Tasks.Task GenerateReportAsync() invoked
[2020-12-22T18:20:17.808Z] System.Threading.Tasks.Task GenerateReportAsync() invoked
[2020-12-22T18:20:17.808Z] System.Threading.Tasks.Task GenerateReportAsync() invoked
[2020-12-22T18:20:18.536Z] Executed 'activity' (Succeeded, Id=caea5602-9c0b-463a-b0b0-112e512eaf25, Duration=878ms)
[2020-12-22T18:20:18.540Z] Executed 'activity' (Succeeded, Id=cc4f89ef-f64c-4851-8e7c-3b7acbfcc915, Duration=901ms)
[2020-12-22T18:20:18.541Z] Executed 'activity' (Succeeded, Id=3a7747a6-5568-4561-a028-9c319263ccf7, Duration=897ms)
[2020-12-22T18:20:18.610Z] Executing 'orchestration' (Reason='(null)', Id=9500673c-7c4d-4d91-bfea-b6e095f51197)
[2020-12-22T18:20:18.716Z] System.Threading.Tasks.Task GenerateReportsAsync() invoked
[2020-12-22T18:20:18.728Z] Executed 'orchestration' (Succeeded, Id=9500673c-7c4d-4d91-bfea-b6e095f51197, Duration=120ms)
[2020-12-22T18:20:18.782Z] Executing 'orchestration' (Reason='(null)', Id=8c9dc2d6-71f9-47b0-8c1a-4409da6b23d7)
[2020-12-22T18:20:18.896Z] System.Threading.Tasks.Task ExecuteAsync() invoked
[2020-12-22T18:20:18.901Z] Executed 'orchestration' (Succeeded, Id=8c9dc2d6-71f9-47b0-8c1a-4409da6b23d7, Duration=120ms)
```

For more about how Functionless makes this possible see its [Autofac Module implementation](https://github.com/LeastOne/Functionless/blob/022a407e664348ccccda1363a1efb1e4f9e7b607/Functionless/Injection/Module.cs#L35)  which contains the following snippet that could be adapted to many other scenarios if you'd like to achieve a similar result with Autofac but without Functionless ...

```
assemblies.ForEach(
    assembly => builder
        .RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
        .Where(p => p.IsPublic && p.IsClass)
        .AsSelf().AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .PreserveExistingDefaults()
        .EnableClassInterceptors()
        .InterceptedBy(interceptorTypes)
);
```